# Sorting a list in python based on the last number in each string entry

Tags: python, regex, string, sorting, numbers

I have a list in python of the following form:

```
myList = ['r0x94', 'r0x21', 'r0x51']
```

I want to sort it based on the last number in each string entry of the list such that:

```
sorted_myList = ['r0x21', 'r0x51', 'r0x94']
```

The last number is not hex, rather it is decimal. How to do it?

Comment: `myList.sort()`

Comment: Starting `0x` are the values hex?

Comment: No, the ending values are decimal, not hex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> my_list = ['r0x94', 'r0x21', 'r0x51']
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: int(x.rpartition('x')[-1]))
['r0x21', 'r0x51', 'r0x94']
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's better than `sorted(my_list)`...

Comment: It is better, try with `['r0x94', 'r0x21', 'r0x51', 'r0x100', 'r0x10']`

Comment: @MartinEvans Try it with `['r0x1A']`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann  The question author never said whether this is hex or not, he just said the last number in the string. So im voting to close the question

Comment: Well, I'd say the `0x` suggests hex. But really that was my response to Martin and my point is that if we assume the OP's example isn't representative, then I'd think of hex before thinking of changing the size.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'd think that too if it weren't for the `r` in front of it

Comment: The ending values are not hex, they are decimal